# Probability of a success at the k-th trial in N repeated Bernoulli trials

Tags: probability, bernoulli-distribution

For a Bernoulli random variable with success probability $p$, how does one compute the probability of having a ''success'' at the $k$-th trial out of $N$ repeated and independent trials where $k \le N$ ?

Comment: Isn't it just $p$? Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question.

Answer (score 1):

As described in [more general case here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/198198/how-many-random-selections-needed-to-be-90-95-99-confident-that-a-specific/198202#198202), it follows [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution). You have $k$ independent trials with the same probability of success $p$, so you expect $k-1$ failures and then a success, what translates to

$$ \underbrace{(1-p)\times(1-p)\times\dots\times(1-p)}_{k-1 ~ \text{failures}} \times \underbrace{p}_{\text{success}} = (1-p)^{k-1}p $$